# is there a complete list of rspec api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, matcher

newbie.  I would like a full list of the rspec api - particularly the built in matchers.  It appears this web site: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/built-in-matchers  appears to be done base on version.

the problem I have is, lets say I need a have(n).items matcher.  I would have no idea this matcher existed by looking at version 3.4.  I would potentially have to view all ~20 versions to discover it.  Why is it done this way?  Doesn't this seem like an awkward way to publish an API? is there a full list somewhere?  :)

Answer (score 1):

That matcher was removed in RSpec 3:

http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/

To find which matchers are available, check your Gemfile.lock to see which version of RSpec is in use, then refer to the corresponding documentation.